# Need advice cleaning my code to make it DRY

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dry

I'm doing an exercise where I need to create a code there I set a speed limit of 70m/h.
For every increment in 5miles the code will add 1 point and after 5 points the license gets revoked.

the way that I made the code works, but is too repetitive, I can't think of a way to make it more simple with loops  to not have to repeat so many times.

Any advice?

```
def speed_check(speed):
    speed_limit = 70
    points = 0

    if speed <= speed_limit:
        return "Speed is OK"
    elif (speed < speed_limit + 5) and (speed > speed_limit):
        points += 1
        return "Points taken {}!".format(points)
    elif (speed < speed_limit + 10) and (speed > speed_limit):
        points += 2
        return "Points taken {}!".format(points)
    elif (speed < speed_limit + 15) and (speed > speed_limit):
        points += 3
        return "Points taken {}!".format(points)
    elif (speed < speed_limit + 20) and (speed > speed_limit):
        points += 4
        return "Points taken {}!".format(points)
    else:
        points += 5
        return "Points taken {}!\nYour license has been revoked".format(points)


your_speed = int(input("Enter speed: "))
print(speed_check(your_speed))
```

Comment: You know, when your code is in an elif, the conditions from the prior associated ifs and elifs are already known to be false. You don't have to keep rechecking things you already ruled out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math

def speed_check(speed):
    speed_limit = 70
    points = 0

    if speed > speed_limit:
      amountOverSpeedLimit = (speed - speed_limit)
      points = math.floor(amountOverSpeedLimit/5)

    return "Points taken {}!".format(points)

your_speed = int(input("Enter speed: "))
print(speed_check(your_speed))
```

You can use `math.floor` and some division to achieve the same results. This doesn't solve for the message when you've gone over 4 points or for when your speed is not over the limit, but you should be able to add that in.